# Can I install a Micromax Canvas Juice ROM on a Micromax Bolt?

Tags: rom

actually I want to install a Samsung galaxy s5 ROM on my micromax bolt a068 but I was not able to find such ROM for my device on the internet but now I found a s5 ROM for micromax canvas juice ant this device is almost similar to my device,only one the processor is not same I have a 1 GHz processor and it has a 1.3 GHz processor.
so my question is that can I use that ROM for my device. is it safe to do so.
 thankyou

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use a ROM for a different device. The ROM needs to be for the same device. In most cases, the flashing tool will detect that you're using the wrong ROM and stop you, but in some cases, or if you disable the warning, it will simply brick the device.